# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient" not found

Tags: php, api, sdk, zoho

I am trying to connect zoho crm to my website to read data. I cannot get past the title error.
I have installed the sdk in my folder through `composer require zohocrm/php-sdk`. I am also including the name space at the top of the file `use zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient;`. So I am not sure what else to try. There is very little documentation on this sdk.

Thanks

This is my php file

```
<?php
use zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient;
// session_start();

require 'vendor\autoload.php';


$configuration=array("client_id"=>"1000.<client_ID>","client_secret"=>"<client_secret>","redirect_uri"=>"www.google.com","currentUserEmail"=>"marktok206@gmail.com");
ZCRMRestClient::initialize($configuration);

echo "working rn";
?>
```

This is my .json file

```
{
    "require": {
        "zohocrm/php-sdk": "^3.1"
    }
}
```